# ddply has different output depending on sorting/order of .variables used to apply function

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, plyr

My full data (results of `dput()`) is at the end of the question. I'm trying to make a tile plot with `ggplot()` and have unevenly spaced `x` and `y` measurements, so the tiles don't fill out the full area. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = -y, z = d)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = d))
```

[image: unevenly space tiles]

I don't know for sure, but I think `ggplot` might default to a tile size of something like `unique(data$x)[2] - unique(data$x)[1]`, hence the rows of my data where this is, indeed, the distance between consecutive `x` or `y` measurements touch, but not the rest. I figured I'd make a `height` and `width` column for my data using `plyr` and `ddply()`, but am experiencing odd results.

For those who aren't going to load the full data, here's the structure:

```
head(data, 5)

     x y       d
1  2.0 0 0.28125
2  5.5 0 0.81250
3 11.5 0 0.56250
4 17.5 0 0.46875
5 23.5 0 0.40625

tail(data, 5)

       x    y     d
191 47.5 80.5 0.000
192 53.5 80.5 0.125
193 59.5 80.5 0.000
194 65.5 80.5 0.000
195 71.0 80.5 0.000
```

So, I'm cycling through every value of `x` for each unique value of `y`. Here's how I tried setting a height/width column:

```
# for each unique value of y, calculate diff for the x's and then add on 1
data$width <- ddply(data, .(y), summarize, width = c(diff(x), 1))$width

# for each unique value of x, calculate diff for the y's and then add on 1
data$height <- ddply(data, .(x), summarize, height = c(diff(y), 1))$height
```

I just threw on a `1` at the end since the length of `diff()` for `n` values is `n-1` and I thought I'd play with the correct value to concatenate later. Here's what I'm getting, though:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = -y, z = d)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = d, height = height, width = width))
```

[image: wrong heights]

The widths are correct, but not the heights. Upon investigating:

```
head(data, 5)

      x y       d height width
1   2.0 0 0.28125    5.5   3.5
2   5.5 0 0.81250    6.5   6.0
3  11.5 0 0.56250    6.0   6.0
4  17.5 0 0.46875    6.0   6.0
5  23.5 0 0.40625    6.0   6.0
```

So, we can see that the widths are correct: 2 -> 5.5 = 3.5, 5.5 -> 11.5 = 6, and so on.

But the heights are not, which we can see if we just look the output of constant `x` values:

```
head(data[data$x == 2, ], 5)

    x    y       d height width
1   2  0.0 0.28125    5.5   3.5
14  2  5.5 0.37500    4.5   3.5
27  2 12.0 0.37500    4.5   3.5
40  2 18.0 0.56250    6.0   3.5
53  2 24.0 0.25000    6.0   3.5
```

The first should be 5.5 (correct), but the second should be 6.5, then 6, and so on.

If I manually run my `ddply` function by subsetting myself, it seems to work:

```
c(diff(data[data$x == 2, "y"]), 1)
 [1] 5.5 6.5 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 4.5 5.5 4.5 1.0
```

In re-examining the `height` values, they appeared to be *the same*, but *re-arranged*. Following that observation, I re-sorted my data as though I'd collected data for each unique `x` while holding `y` constant, instead of the other way around, and then re-defined my `height` and `width` columns:

```
data_sort <- data[order(data$y, data$x), c("x", "y", "d")]
data_sort$width <- ddply(data_sort, .(y), summarize, width = c(diff(x), 1))$width
data_sort$height <- ddply(data_sort, .(x), summarize, height = c(diff(y), 1))$height
```

Heights are now correct, but widths are jumbled:

```
head(data_sort, 5)
   x    y       d width height
1  2  0.0 0.28125   3.5    5.5
14 2  5.5 0.37500   6.0    6.5
27 2 12.0 0.37500   6.0    6.0
40 2 18.0 0.56250   6.0    6.0
53 2 24.0 0.25000   6.0    6.0
66 2 30.0 0.31250   6.0    6.0
```

What am I missing that `ddply` isn't keeping things in order when searching over unique but non-consecutive levels/values?

---

The data:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(x = c(2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 
47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 
41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 
35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 
29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 
23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 
17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 
5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 
71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 
65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 
59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 
53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 
47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 
41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 29.5, 
35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 23.5, 
29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71, 2, 5.5, 11.5, 17.5, 
23.5, 29.5, 35.5, 41.5, 47.5, 53.5, 59.5, 65.5, 71), y = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
54, 54, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 66, 
66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 
70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 
80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5, 80.5), 
    d = c(0.28125, 0.8125, 0.5625, 0.46875, 0.40625, 0.3125, 
    0.25, 0.125, 0.09375, 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.25, 0, 0.375, 0.46875, 
    0.5, 0.4375, 0.4375, 0.3125, 0.28125, 0.1875, 0.125, 0.0625, 
    0.1875, 0.3125, 0.5, 0.375, 0.25, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.375, 0.3125, 
    0.28125, 0.15625, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.3125, 0.5, 0.5625, 
    0.375, 0.4375, 0.40625, 0.375, 0.3125, 0.25, 0.15625, 0.09375, 
    0.0625, 0.125, 0.28125, 0.3125, 0.25, 0.34375, 0.40625, 0.40625, 
    0.375, 0.3125, 0.21875, 0.125, 0.09375, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 
    0.3125, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.40625, 0.40625, 0.375, 0.3125, 0.21875, 
    0.09375, 0.0625, 0, 0.09375, 0.15625, 0.25, 0.28125, 0.34375, 
    0.40625, 0.4375, 0.4375, 0.375, 0.3125, 0.1875, 0.15625, 
    0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.46875, 
    0.46875, 0.4375, 0.375, 0.28125, 0.5625, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 
    0.34375, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0.4375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4375, 0.34375, 
    0.21875, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.34375, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0.4375, 
    0.46875, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4375, 0.34375, 0.21875, 0.09375, 0.15625, 
    0.3125, 0.34375, 0.25, 0.34375, 0.34375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.6875, 
    0.3125, 0.1875, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.125, 
    0.21875, 0.28125, 0.28125, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1875, 0.09375, 0.0625, 
    0.0625, 0.1875, 0.3125, 0.4375, 0, 0.125, 0.1875, 0.1875, 
    0.21875, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.28125, 0.15625, 0.125, 0.125, 
    0.375, 0.625, 0, 0.0625, 0.09375, 0.09375, 0.21875, 0.21875, 
    0.21875, 0.21875, 0.1875, 0.15625, 0.4375, 0.625, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.09375, 0.125, 0.125, 0.09375, 0.0625, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 
    0)), .Names = c("x", "y", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -195L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly, silly, silly.

`ddply`'s output re-arranges things into the order it processes them and I completely ignored (forgot/was ignorant) of that fact when I extracted just the output of the `height` column. So, even though my data was sorted first by `y`'s and then `x`'s, when I called `ddply` to compute something based on unique `x`'s and /then/ `y`'s, that's how it provided the output.

Just to show this:

```
head(data)
     x y       d
1  2.0 0 0.28125
2  5.5 0 0.40625
3 11.5 0 0.56250
4 17.5 0 0.46875
5 23.5 0 0.40625
6 29.5 0 0.31250
```

And looking at the full output of my `ddply` call shows that that `y`'s are grouped just how they appear in the original data, so `cbind`ing that column in as `data$width` works fine:

```
widths <- ddply(data, .(y), summarize, width = c(diff(x), 1))
head(widths)
  y width
1 0   3.5
2 0   6.0
3 0   6.0
4 0   6.0
5 0   6.0
6 0   6.0
```

But when I did that for the heights, the data was grouped by unique `x`'s, which is not how my data is arranged:

```
heights <- ddply(data, .(x), summarize, height = c(diff(y), 1))
head(heights)
  x height
1 2    5.5
2 2    6.5
3 2    6.0
4 2    6.0
5 2    6.0
6 2    6.0
```

Certainly didn't warrant a question -- by extracting just the column I wanted, I completely overlooked the form of the `ddply` output compared to my data.

To get around this, I probably should have created two data frames with both the `x` and `y` values along with `height` and `width` (calculated from `diff()`), and then merged them by unique combinations of `x` and `y`.